# Align object to view with Python

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view

I was trying to a add a plane primitive using Blender Python and aligning it to the viewport.

I already tried setting `align_view = True` when adding it via Python, but it doesn't change the rotation at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_*()` operators need to be run in a proper context (3D View) in order to use `align_view`.

Either run an operator via Spacebar menu, or use an override:

```
import bpy

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        for region in area.regions:
            if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                ctx = bpy.context.copy()
                ctx['area'] = area
                ctx['region'] = region
                bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(ctx, view_align=True)
                break
```

Note that there seems to be a bug, the plane appears to be in *Edit mode*, but the UI reports *Object Mode*, and the face may be missing.