# How to get cursor snap status in python?

Tags: python, snapping

Is there a way to determine if the cursor /object  is currently snap on object? In this case on the face:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Closest Point on Mesh**

[`Object.closest_point_on_mesh(...)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.closest_point_on_meshhttps://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.closest_point_on_mesh)

Takes a point in object space and returns the hit result, the location of hit, the normal of face hit and the face's index.

Alternatively could utilize [`mathutils.geometry.distance_point_to_plane(...)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/mathutils.geometry.html?highlight=mathutils%20geometry#mathutils.geometry.distance_point_to_plane), where each plane is defined by face center and face normal. *Edit, this is somewhat flawed since the cursor can be on a faces plane but outside its edges, which would need to be tested for*

Both these methods require the point to be in object space.  The 3d cursor location is in global space, convert using

```
pt = o.matrix_world.inverted() @ scene.cursor.location
```

Here is a verbose script using both methods.  The `on_face` boolean is true if cursor is on face of an object.

Note testing shows the tolerance `TOL` (distance from point to face) needs to be in the vicinity of `5e-5`

```
import bpy
from mathutils.geometry import distance_point_to_plane as dp2p
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene

dg = context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
TOL = 5e-5 # Tolerance

mesh_obs = [o for o in context.scene.objects if o.type == 'MESH']

for o in mesh_obs:
    me = o.data
    print(o.name, me.name)
    #cursor location in o's object space
    pt = o.matrix_world.inverted() @ scene.cursor.location

    # using closest point on mesh
    hit, loc, n, i = o.closest_point_on_mesh(pt, depsgraph=dg)

    print(i, (pt - loc).length)

    on_face = hit and (pt - loc).length < TOL
    print("closest point on mesh", on_face)

    # using distance point to plane for each face


    for p in me.polygons:
        print(p.index, dp2p(pt, p.center, p.normal))

    on_face = any(abs(dp2p(pt, p.center, p.normal)) < TOL
            for p in me.polygons)
    print("plane distance", on_face)
```

Result of running on default cube after clicking to snap cursor to face from view.

```
Cube Cube
3 2.1159816795005355e-05
closest point on mesh True
0 -0.9940524101257324
1 -1.0059475898742676
2 -1.1975289583206177
3 2.104043960571289e-05
4 -0.8024709224700928
5 -2.000020980834961
plane distance True
```

Related [Snappping the 3D cursor to the surface and find the surface's face it was snapped to](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92720/snappping-the-3d-cursor-to-the-surface-and-find-the-surfaces-face-it-was-snappe?rq=1)